Getting Around 3rd Party Cookies on Vercel
I am migrating a React app over to Vercel. I am using Render to host my backend. Everything works fine except I get notified about 3rd party cookies being unsafe. When I update my cookie issuing policy to samesite='strict' instead of samesite='None' I can see that my headers are no longer sending cookies.
I think this is expected since my frontend uses a Go Daddy domain and it seems like Render creates its own backend domain.
I'm wondering if anyone has used these services before and could point me in the right direction towards resolving the 3rd party cookie issue.
